# Class protocols not working after updating from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a very basic user class, who os responsible for get user data from Firebase and update the currently screen if needed, everything was working until a decided to update my project to Swift 3.0

This is the User Class

```
    @objc protocol userClassProtocol {
        func updateScreen() 
        @objc optional func sucessUnlockedCategory() 
    }

class User {
   static let sharedInstance = User()
   internal var delegate : userClassProtocol?

   func fakeClassThatGetsDataFromFirebase() {
       //Got data
       print("Has new data")
       self.delegate?.updateScreen()
   }
}
```

And here is the ViewController:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, userClassProtocol {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("View will load")
        User.sharedInstance.delegate = self
    }

    func updateScreen() {
        print("Screen is going to update")
        //Do stuff here
    }
}
```

The logs i get from this are:
   Has new Data
   View Will Appear

But the function updateScreen() in the view controller never gets called. No errors are being pointed out by Xcode.

Comment: Do you call fakeClassThatGetsDataFromFirebase after you set delegate?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's just an issue with the timing of your method calls.

Your `fakeClassThatGetsDataFromFirebase` method is called first, and at that point, your delegate hasn't been set. So `self.delegate` is `nil` when calling:

`self.delegate?.updateScreen()`

This will only work if your `viewWillAppear` gets called before `fakeClassThatGetsDataFromFirebase`

Comment: You are in to something, i changed the code in button that triggers fakeClassThatGetsDataFromFirebase to call  User.sharedInstance.delegate = self before calling that function, and it worked, the thing is that this exact same code was working before ( Swift 2.3 ), and in theory viewWillAppear is being called before fakeClassThatGetsDataFromFirebase every time.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that something else in your Swift 3 conversion could have messed with the order of how things are called. Perhaps you should move setting your delegate to an init method in `FirstViewController`, or at least higher up the call chain into `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Did this help you get to the bottom of things? If so, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't get called, according to your code. Nothing calls `fakeClassThatGetsDataFromFirebase()`, which is what should call `updateScreen()` on your delegate method.

Comment: fakeClassThaGetsDataFromFirebase is called every time a change has being made in the Firebase Database data, i did not put this is code because was to big, but i getting the print("Has new data"), that is inside the function.